# JQuery Dialog - execute code only when clicking "X" Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a dialog with two buttons (Yes-No). Each one triggers a function

```
$('#divDialog').dialog({
    modal:true,
    width:450,
    resizable: false,          
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Yes',
        click: function () {
            /*Do stuff when clicking yes*/
        }},{
            text: 'No',                
            click: function () {
                /*Do stuff when clicking no*/
            }}],
    close: function(ev, ui){
        /*Do stuff always when closing*/                 
    }
});
```

What I want to do is execute the same code as in the "No" button when you click the "X" button on top. So I put that code in the "close" function. But then the code is also executed when clicking "Yes".

How can I execute that code when clicking "X" but not when clicking "Yes"?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't put the code you don't want to execute on a certain event inside that event callback. Just factorize it in a different way.

Comment: Just get the buttons to return either`true` or `false` and pick them up as arguments in another function

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to define a function and call it wherever needed, like  below.

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/es1jomez/1/)

```
function myFunction() {
    alert ("I am clicked");
}

$('#divDialog').dialog({
    modal:true,
    width:450,
    resizable: false,          
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Yes',
        click: function() {}
    }, {
        text: 'No',                
        click: myFunction
    }],
    close: myFunction
});
```

Answer (score 0):

define a function and call it when user clicks yes or closes dialog.

```
 $('#divDialog').dialog({
          modal:true,
          width:450,
          resizable: false,          
          buttons: [{
                text: 'Yes',
                click: function () {
                    /*Do stuff when clicking yes*/
                    do_work();
                }},{
                text: 'No',                
                click: function () {
                    /*Do stuff when clicking no*/
          }}],
          close: function(ev, ui){
                     /*Do stuff always when closing*/                 
                    do_work();
                }
       });

function do_work() {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would put the `do_work()` method decleration outside, and then do `close:do_work`

Comment: passing a variable to do_work(showAlert) is not working, the variable inside do_work() coming as undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with declaring on function outside of the jQueryUI init :

```
var onClick = function(ev, ui) {
    console.log(ev);
    if(ev.type == "click") {
        this.isYes = (ev.originalEvent.currentTarget.textContent == "Yes")
        $(this).dialog('close');
    } else {
        if(this.isYes){
            alert("Yes");
        } else {
            alert("No");
        }
    }
}

$('#divDialog').dialog({
    modal:true,
    width:450,
    resizable: false,          
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Yes',
        click: onClick
    },{
        text: 'No',                
        click: onClick
    }],
    close: onClick
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nu47ubwq/7/)

Comment: The problem is I need to close the dialog both when clicking yes and no, so I need to finish both onYes and onNo with $('#divDialog').dialog('close'). Then the close function gets executed no matter what you click.

Comment: Yes, my scenario is a little bit different but this set me in the right track, thanks!